# Samsung S6 disabled button text disappears

Tags: c#, android, button, xamarin.forms

I have a Xamarin.Forms shared project and I have just stumbled upon a weird behavior that is related to Samsung S6 running Android 7. I have not been able to recreate the issue on any other device, no matter what Android it was running.

In my Android project I am using the native theme for the app (global::Android.Resource.Style.ThemeDeviceDefault), which means that all the controls have their look based on the system the app is installed on.

It works fine on every device that I have tried so far, except Samsung S6, where disabled buttons do not display their text anymore. Once they are re-enabled, the text appears again. You can see it here: https://i.stack.imgur.com/reIgy.jpg

Is there any way to deal with this issue? I know I can just use a standard theme on every device, but I kind of like the idea that the controls look native on every device.

Comment: Have you confirmed that the color of the button and text after it is disabled are different?

Comment: I have thought of that too, I think it could be the case, but I have no way of changing the color of a disabled button in Xamarin.Forms without using a custom renderer.

Comment: You can change stuff in <Project-Name>.Droid/Resources/values/styles.xml instead of creating a custom renderer. I'd confirm the colors of the button and text first before jumping down that rabbit hole.

Comment: I am not sure what do you mean, this is the ThemeDeviceDefault theme, which implies it uses the device setting, I cannot really influence it no?